# How to remove duplicate records

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite 3.11. I create a table as follows:

```
            CREATE TABLE MyTable (F1 INTEGER, F2 INTEGER, F3 INTEGER);
```

Then add the following records:

```
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (1, 2, 8); 
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (1, 3, 9);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (2, 4, 8);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (2, 5, 2);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (3, 6, 4);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (3, 7, 8);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (3, 7, 9);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (4, 2, 4);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (4, 2, 6);
```

Now I want to eliminate duplicate record so for two records whose F1 and F2 values are identical, even if their F3 values are different, then one record with the largest value of F3 will be kept and the other one will be removed.

Is that possible with the DELETE statement?

Thanks

Comment: Can you write the checksum function for your triplets? This can made ease the comparison

Comment: For example, `f1*1 000 000 000 + f2*1 000 000 + f3` ?

Comment: Is there a primary key set for this table?

Answer (score 0):

First, construct a query that finds all records to be deleted:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE F3 < (SELECT MAX(F3)
            FROM MyTable AS T2
            WHERE T2.F1 = MyTable.F1
              AND T2.F2 = MyTable.F2);
```

Then use a unique field of the table (in this case, the internal [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)) to delete them:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE F3 < (SELECT MAX(F3)
                            FROM MyTable AS T2
                            WHERE T2.F1 = MyTable.F1
                              AND T2.F2 = MyTable.F2));
```

Comment: I just follow your idea and write another statement to keep one record and remove the duplicates. The kept one is not the one with the largest value of F3, instead, it is selected randomly. My query is

DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT rowid FROM MyTable AS T2 WHERE (T2.F1 = MyTable.F1) AND (T2.F2 = MyTable.F2) LIMIT 1);

I try some tests and it works. Please kindly tell me whether my statement is correct or if there are any optimizations that can done on it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I want to unify my statement as follows:

DELETE FROM MyTable AS T2 WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT rowid FROM MyTable AS T2 WHERE (T2.F1 = T1.F1) AND (T2.F2 = T1.F2) LIMIT 1);

But that will cause syntax error on the first "AS" clause. Why? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you trying to write a different statement?

Comment: Because there are two cases, for one case, I need to get the record with maximum value of F3, for another case, I only need to get one record randomly. Thank you very much.

Comment: So it wouldn't be wrong to use the maximum in every case, would it?

Comment: Yes, maximum will be used for some cases. Actually to print peak value of F3. While random selected record will be used for other cases when F3 is not important.